# Name for holder of focus?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm looking for a word that describes the "holder" of focus.

*Sample sentence:*
Focus rewards its `<insert suggested word here>`.

*Criteria for best:* appropriate and can only be used to describe one who focuses. Preferably relative to the same instance of focus as in example.

*Other words considered:* owner (too general), single-minded (not specific to single instance of focus but rather a generic trait).

Single word is preferable but compound, phrase or an alternate expression would be appropriate.

Comment: What kind of focus? You mean paying attention, rather than what a camera does? You want a word for the person paying attention, rather than what they are studying.

Comment: [Focuser](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/focuser) is in dictionaries.

Comment: It looks to me as if the OP here is trying to "translate" a "proverb, saying, aphorism" from some other language into English. We do have, for example, ***Virtue is its own reward***, but I don't think we could meaningfully adapt that structure to anything involving ***focus***. Except maybe with a bit of facetious alliteration - for example, ***Fixed focus is fulfilling***.